# Fetching picklist values in LWC doesn't work

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to fetch picklist options from a custom picklist field on a custom object.

When I wrote up my code like below, it worked.

```html
picklistPractice.html

<template>
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
        <lightning-combobox label="My Picklist" options={picklistValues}>

        </lightning-combobox>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
picklistPractice.js

import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import PROJECT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Project__c';
import DINNER_MENU_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project__c.Dinner_Menu__c';

export default class PicklistPractice extends LightningElement {
    picklistValues = [];

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: PROJECT_OBJECT})
    projectObjectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { 
        recordTypeId: '$projectObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
        fieldApiName: DINNER_MENU_FIELD
    })
    getDinnerMenuOptions({data, error}) {
        if (error) {
            // TODO: Error handling
            console.error(error)
        } else if (data) {
            this.picklistValues = [...data.values]
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

**However,** when I used a property instead of a function for the second `@wire`, it didn't work.
Below is the js code that didn't work. html file is the same as above.

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import PROJECT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Project__c';
import DINNER_MENU_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project__c.Dinner_Menu__c';

export default class PicklistPractice extends LightningElement {

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: PROJECT_OBJECT})
    projectObjectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { 
        recordTypeId: '$projectObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
        fieldApiName: DINNER_MENU_FIELD
    })
    picklistValues;
}
```

Can anyone let me know why the second way is not working? I've seen a few articles like [Get picklist values after dynamically fetching the record type id in lwc](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/329238/get-picklist-values-after-dynamically-fetching-the-record-type-id-in-lwc) but I wasn't able to figure out why mine didn't work.

---

---

Thanks for your answer! Actually I tried to use `picklistValues.data.values` before posting this question ;).. See below... It threw an error.

[image]

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
        <lightning-combobox label="My Picklist" options={picklistValues.data.values}>

        </lightning-combobox>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import PROJECT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Project__c';
import DINNER_MENU_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project__c.Dinner_Menu__c';

export default class PicklistPractice extends LightningElement {

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: PROJECT_OBJECT})
    projectObjectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { 
        recordTypeId: '$projectObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
        fieldApiName: DINNER_MENU_FIELD
    })
    picklistValues;
}
```

This isn't a huge problem for me right now because I can use a function instead of the property, but I'm wondering **WHY NOT** as an LWC newbie :).

Comment: Try updating the options porperty on your combobox component to something like: `options={picklistValues.data.values}`

Comment: @McCubo - Thanks for your answer! I actually used that before posting this question.. but it didn't work as well. It threw an error..  I appended some additional contents in my question body.

Comment: Try wrapping up your combobox component in a if template like this one: `<template lwc:if={picklistValues.data}>`

Comment: @McCubo Thanks!! That worked perfectly. I might have to look for how LWC manages a component's lifecycle. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

See how the wired `picklistValues` property is used in this [LWC recipe](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/0e988eb922a4dc6814fe96c15604c7e61becd284/force-app/main/default/lwc/wireGetPicklistValues/wireGetPicklistValues.html):

```
 <template for:each={picklistValues.data.values} for:item="item">
```

Personally, I always use a function so that the property is directly set to the value/values I want. That also allows any errors to be surfaced.

Comment: Thanks Keith! I've already seen that recipe but it didn't work for me as well. Updated my question with the error screenshot when I used `picklistValues.data.values`. Though this is not a huge problem for me right now because I can use a function, I simply wanted to know why it didn't work.. :)

Comment: FYI @MinsungKang, I was surprised to see `data` in that. Would have expected `picklistValues.values`.